# Publish/subscribe with Node.js and Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe, node-redis

I'm trying to get Redis pub/sub working in a little Node app. Currently I'm using node-redis and I don't understand the API for pub/sub. It seems like I can subscribe to a channel by name and then I receive all messages for all channels in a generic 'message' event, like so:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = app.listen(4000) 
  , sio = require('socket.io') 
  , io = sio.listen(server)
  , db = require('redis').createClient();

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     db.subscribe("foo");
     db.subscribe("bar");
     db.on("message", function(channel, message) {
         socket.emit('message', message);                
     });
  });
```

This forces me to either create a new client for each subscription or to use something like:

```
db.on("message", function(channel, message) {
 socket.emit(channel, message);                
});
```

and then listen to the right socket.io channel client side. Neither is ideal for me.

What I would like is to register a callback at the time of subscribing so, I receive messages for that channel only, like in this pseudo code snippet:

```
db.subscribe("foo", function(message) {
    socket.emit("foo_message", message);
});

db.subscribe("bar", function(message) {
    socket.emit("bar_message", message);
});
```

Does anybody know a clean solution for my problem or maybe another redis API that supports my wishes?

Comment: If you don't want to use multiple clients, I don't think it's possible. Redis' `subscribe` is like a subscription to *any* messages on the subscribed channels (although, given your example, you could always use `socket.emit(channel + '_message', message)`, but I bet it's not that easy ;-)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @user2032220 no, I'm still using the workaround of having one client per channel